# Youtube clip auto play and start from beginning when pressed

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to have an embed YouTube clip on your website that auto-plays when you load the page and when you press the clip it starts from the beginning

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

I looked around but I can't find the specific functionality I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto play policy has been changed. 
( https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes )

If you want to autoplay, add "mute". (Tested in Chrome)

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1&mute=1">
</iframe>
```

And you can control the youtube video with JavaScript.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

It can be implemented variously. I made a sample. (use "seekTo" API) 
https://jsfiddle.net/raykim2414/uv7b6ty4/15/

Comment: Yes, thank you, for the update but I am also asking if it's possible to add a functionality that restarts the clip when the user presses the iframe?

Comment: I didn't exactly understand your question. You can use "seekTo" I added a link to the document.